# ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 login problem

Tags: boot, upgrade

After upgrading to 13.10 from 13.04 Ubuntu. I have left the downloading and installation process running over night and due to power cut system shutdown itself. I am sure that downloading and installation was over by the time the power went off. Now, I am unable to login into system. System hangs after giving user password. It is giving error and asks if I want to report the problem. The mouse cursor unable to select the ok button and system not responding.

How to repair? I have lot of data in my 13.04 Ubuntu.

I am using windows 8 as dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
After booting I did <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

then logged in

at the prompt I entered

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After a few minutes I could get the graphical user interface.

This leaves only one more problem, my mouse is not working. I am using Microsoft wireless
mouse. I tried with a wired mouse also, but in vain.